# How can I import eml files in mu4e on emacs?

Tags: email, emacs, mu

I've recently started to use Emacs. I'm using mu4e for my mail which is downloaded via Mbsync and indexed using Mu.

Is there any way to import thousands of emails on my hard drive in the .eml format?

I'm on OSX El Capitan

Answer (score 2):

I actually find that if you put the eml files in a cur folder and run mu index, it finds all the emails!